# What is a Bingo Book?

Tags: naruto

It was only mentioned once or twice in the show. Did different villages have different Bingo Books or did everyone share information on the wanted ninja? Was there a price for their heads? Or was it just a book about wanted targets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bingo books](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Bingo_Book) are designed to contain a list of names, along with all known information, that are to be targets for various reasons; whether it be for the price on their heads or to be killed on sight due to being a threat

> Bingo Books are black books used by ninja that contain any and all information on black-listed ninja they are to target. There are multiple versions of the Bingo Books, the most common being those based from the Hidden Villages.

A majority of the time, Bingo Books put together by high ranking officials to have intel on Shinobi ranging from either missing-nin or deadly Shiboni from other villages

> Normally, Bingo Book entries are compiled by a village's high ranking officials, usually the Kage, that are then distributed to its jōnin and Anbu members. Those listed are typically dangerous ninja from rival villages, missing-nin, or potential security threats that are to be eliminated given the opportunity. A unit of Anbu from Kirigakure, the hunter-nin, have the sole purpose of eradicating missing-nin so that no physical trace of their body remains.

Other versions of Bingo Books that are seen are by the Akatsuki that contain the list of jinchūrikis

> The Akatsuki, on the other hand, use their Bingo Book for the more sinister purpose of listing their jinchūriki targets and certain ninja from the villages who have potential use to them.

And Kakazu, which contain a list of Shinobi with bounties on their heads

> In Kakuzu's case, he lists his Bingo Book with information on various ninja with large bounties on their heads so that he can claim the bounty on them.